# Convert Ubuntu 10.04 into a server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx Desktop version installed and am interested in running it as a server. I have already installed Apache, PHP, and MySQL.

I am completely new to server administration. Would somebody please point me in a good direction to setting this up? I am sure there are numerous tutorials online, but I just can't seem to find one.

**Update**

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 Server Edition and, with some help from [serverfault](http://www.serverfault.com) (seemed more appropriate for server-related questions) am now able to connect to it from my Windows box so that I can test my PHP/MySQL projects in a browser. I also was able to connect to `/var/www` by using sftp through my FTP software.

Thanks for everybody's help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Ubuntu Server Edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition)?

- Reference to [documentation for the Ubuntu Server Edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition/documentation).
- HowToForge: [The Perfect Server - Ubuntu Lucid Lynx (Ubuntu 10.04)](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-10.04-lucid-lynx-ispconfig-2)
- [Frequently Asked Questions about the Ubuntu Server Edition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq)

  - The "Server" CD avoids including what Ubuntu considers desktop packages (packages like X, Gnome or KDE) but includes server related packages (Apache2, Bind9 and so on). Using a Desktop CD with a minimal installation and installing, for example, apache2 from the network, one can obtain the exact same result that can be obtained by inserting the Server CD and installing apache2 from the cd-rom.
  - The Ubuntu Server Edition installation process is slightly different then the Desktop Edition. Since by default Ubuntu Server doesn't have a GUI the process is menu driven, very similar to the Alternate CD installation process.
  - Can I add a "Graphic User Interface" (GUI) To a Server?
    While we don't recommend running X system on a server for security and performance reason, yes you can. Depending on what window manager you wish to use you can install the xserver and the window manager via apt-get. For details see the [ServerGUI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI) page.
- The [Lucid Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/index.html)

Comment: I'd go with this option too.

Comment: @nik Thanks! I just started downloading it. Once running, is it possible to connect to it via ethernet connected directly between two computers? Or do I need to use a router?

Comment: @nik, that is wonderful, thank-you. I can't believe I couldn't find that myself.

Comment: You don't really need a router, but if a typical ethernet cable might not work. If not, you can use an Ethernet crossover cable (it has a couple of wires flipped). Just remember to set both IP addresses to the same subnet so they can talk, and check the firewall settings if that doesn't work.

Comment: @kainosnous - thanks, I think I will go pick up a router tomorrow. Makes more sense, I believe.

Comment: What you would need to do is tell the other computer to "Share" internet access over the ethernet port (and have it connected via wireless or a different ethernet port). This will set up a DHCP server which is only visible to the device(s) connected to the port. If you want all the computers to be on the same subnet and be able to talk to each other, you'll need to set up a network bridge (software thing) from the ethernet port to the interface with internet access, which is very complicated. Oh, and you won't need a crossover cable unless you're dealing with very old hardware (>10 years).

Comment: @nik Thanks for the information, I did end up going with the server edition. After some time familiarizing myself with text-only commands, it's actually fun!

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is to tell you that a quick Google search gives the following: http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_debian_lamp_server

However, for my personal advice, I would suggest starting with the basics and working your way up. First, install and configure Apache. Apache has a great website and manual that can help you with the bits that you don't understand. The default httpd.conf should be fairly easy to understand and modify. Look for DocumentRoot to find out where it will search for files to serve.

Once you are comfortable with Apache, move on to adding PHP. It also has a good website, and there are many tutorials online about adding PHP to Apache. Look through php.ini, but don't worry about it too much if it isn't a production server.

Last of all, I would install and configure MySQL. Run it from the command line first to get the feel for it before trying it from PHP. The MySQL documentation, IMO, is a bit more bothersome than the others, but it has a great quick start tutorial which is all that you need at first.

Also, I find myself going back to the Arch Linux [LAMP](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LAMP) tutorial for advice that is mostly apropriate for any distro.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tasksel`, unmark the `ubuntu-desktop` option and mark `ubuntu-server` option.

You can also mark others options like for LAMP or the Samba server.